# Cannot implicitly convert type void with no input params to string c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to communicate with a scanner and one of the commands is a type `void` command without input parameters.

`BioPluginActX1.GetScannerStatus();` is the `void` command and should return either
"SCANNER_FOUND" or "NO_SCANNER_FOUND". The trouble I am having is how to get the returned value. Does anyone have any ideas on how to retrieve these values?

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: If the method is marked as `void`, how is it going to return anything?

Comment: The error I am getting states it is a type void but on the actual command I have not typed void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a lot of hardware devices like this, there'll be a second call to get the result. So the pattern is:

```
BioPluginActX1.GetScannerStatus();
var result = BioPlugInActX1.Result();
if (result == "NO_SCANNER_FOUND") throw new Exception("Ack!");
```

Comment: Mark, that seem to be proper answer, but with question's title like this it is very unclear if it is indeed true. Consider updating title since you seem to know what the actual goal is.

Comment: Hi Mark, Yes you are indeed correct. There is a result parameter. I was trying to convert the initial command directly into string and getting the error titled. Thanks once again Callum